# Client queue filled by server queue over the internet with ASP.Net and WPF client

Tags: asp.net, wpf, client-server, message-queue

I am trying to find the right approach for an application, that I am trying to develop.
Situation:

ASP.Net Website. User can make a request on a page. The request must result in an item in a qeue on the server. The qeue targeted is specific for each customer.

WPF client at customer site. The WPF client has a local qeue. The qeue gets filled by either polling the qeue on the webserver or getting a message from the web server. The WPF client uses the qeue to display items as specified in the qeue.

Each WPF client user has it's own account and can only access the qeue that is meant for him.

I dont have any constraints yet as to which solution to use, as long as it is .Net technology and the customer only requires my deployment package and the .Net framework. I can't hassle customers to install something like MSMQ.

I think a database on the webserver containing all the requests could do the trick, but I am wondering if there are any other slick methods that could be better.

Cheers, Momoski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to have your clients pull from the web server/service and not try to push updates out to your clients.  There is way to much complexity for a push solution unless you have complete control over all systems involved (i.e. network, firewalls, etc...).

Comment: +1 this is what I would do.  Setup your database to hold the queue.  Your website places the items in the queue.  And finally a webservice that allows your client to poll and interact with the queue as needed.

Establishing a push connection from the server to the client is probably more effort (and opportunity for bugs) than it is worth.  The client can poll pretty frequently and still give a push feel.